# Zend\Http\Request fails in toString() with post values

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm dealing with this *new* Zend Framework release. As seen in the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.http.request.html#quick-start) page, I expect that returning `toString()` there's *POST* content:

```
use Zend\Http\Request;

class RequestTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testARequestWithAPostValue()
    {
        $request = new Request();
        $request->setMethod(Request::METHOD_POST);
        $request->setUri('/foo');
        $request->getPost()->set('foo', 'bar');

        $string = "POST /foo HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\nfoo=bar&";
        $this->assertEquals($string, $request->toString());
    }
}
```

But the area seems to be empty:

```
1) RequestTest::testRequestWithAPostValue
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 'POST /foo HTTP/1.1

-foo=bar&'
+'
```

Zend Framework 2 is installed as vendor by `composer` with `require "zendframework/zend-http": "2.0.6"`. Both in `PHP 5.4.9` and `PHP 5.3.10`.

That's a **bug** or I miss something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say if it is a bug or not. However, behavior appears to be inconsistent or at least not intuitive. Here is the sample that will work as you expected:

```
use Zend\Http\Request;

class RequestTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testARequestWithAPostValue()
    {
        $string = "POST /foo HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\nfoo=bar;bar=foo";
        $request = Request::fromString($string);

        $this->assertEquals($string, $request->toString());
    }
}
```

Echoing $request will output:

```
POST /foo HTTP/1.1

foo=bar;bar=foo
```

Methods naming, documentation and intended use are confusing: Form fields can be stored either as a raw string or as a object parameters. The method *Request::toString()* does not gracefully handle both cases.

When creating the *Request* object from a sting the form fields will be stored as a raw string using the method *Request::setContent()*. When invoking the method *Request::toString()* the method *Request::getContent()* will be called while composing a string representation of the *Request* object;

If you would like to keep the form fields as a object you will have to create a string representation of the *Request* object yourself.

```
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Stdlib\Parameters;

class RequestTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testARequestWithAPostValue()
    {
        $request = new Request();
        $request->setMethod(Request::METHOD_POST);
        $request->setUri('/foo');
        $params = new Parameters();
        $params->set('foo', 'bar');
        $params->set('bar', 'foo');
        $request->setPost($params);

        $str = $request->renderRequestLine() . "\r\n";
        $headers = $request->getHeaders();
        if (!empty($headers)):
            $str .= $headers->toString();
        endif;
        $str .= "\r\n";

        $rawData = '';
        $keys = array_keys($params->toArray());
        foreach ($keys as $name) :
            $rawData .= "$name=" . $request->getPost($name) . ";";
        endforeach;
        $str .= substr($rawData, 0, -1);

        $string = "POST /foo HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\nfoo=bar;bar=foo";
        $this->assertEquals($string, $str);
    }
}
```

Note that there is no separator after the last form field key-value pair.

The use of the "&" character to separate form fields is considered as a bad practice. See [W3C Recommendations - B.2.2 Ampersands in URI attribute values](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2).